# Restrict Mouse Movement while dragging

Tags: java, dialog, mouseevent

So I have created a JDialog, and I have programmed it to move when I drag it
by setting this at the start of the program;
Point point = new Point();

```
int xMouse;
int yMouse;

int x;
int y;
Dimension scrnSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
Rectangle winSize = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();
int taskBarHeight = (scrnSize.height) - (winSize.height);

int width = (scrnSize.width) - 300;
int height = (scrnSize.height) - 153 - taskBarHeight;
```

and then implementing this;

```
 private void BarMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)   {                           
    point.x=evt.getX();
    point.y = evt.getY();
}                                

private void BarMouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                 
    Point p = getLocation();
    x = p.x+evt.getX()-point.x;
    y = p.y+evt.getY()-point.y;
    if (x > width){}
    else if (y > height){}
    else if (x<(0)){}
    else if (y<(0)){}
    else
    {
    setLocation(x, y);
    }
}
```

As you can see I have tried to make it so that when you attempt to drag the box out of the screen it fails. But this is really quite buggy, it sometimes stops before the screen ends and really hinders movement near the edge of the screen. Not to mention that although the dialog stops moving, the mouse keeps moving.

So I was wondering if there was instead any way to create some sort of boarder that the mouse has to operate inside when it tries to drag the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do to limit the location of your `JDialog` is add a `ComponentListener` to it and check its bounds when it is moved. If you see that it is outside the area you want, you set its location to some other point.

```
package main;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JDialog;

public class DialogListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setSize(300, 400);
        dialog.setVisible(true);

        Dimension scrnSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Rectangle winSize = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();

        final Rectangle screen = new Rectangle(scrnSize.width, 2*scrnSize.height - winSize.height);

        dialog.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {            
            @Override
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
                if (!screen.contains(dialog.getBounds()))
                    dialog.setLocation(300, 400);
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

This example sets the location to a fixed point just to ilustrate how the method works. In a real program, you should move the dialog to the closest point inside the screen. Also, if you want to make the mouse be 'locked' in place, you can take a look at the `Robot` class to issue mouse movements programmatically.